# Automatically decrypt hard drive on login

Tags: encryption, windows-7

I use following setup:

```
C:/ - Windows 7 Ultimate
D:/ - Data of user#1
E:/ - Data of user#2
```

I crypted my drive (D:) with BitLocker, but each time on login i have to unlock it manually. The problem is mine entire Profile folder is on D: e.g. Desktop, so when i login my desk is empty, my pinned taskbar items are also vanished, and remain so, even after i unlock my drive. I have to log out and back in to get everything back.

i wouldn't let windows unlock this drive automatically, as i font want user#2 to use my drive.

So my question is: can i let windows unlock my specified drive after i put my password on login screen?

Comment: aww both answers together lead me to solution... what do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start
2. "Manage bitlocker" (That should take you to the BitLocker Drive Encryption control panel window)
3. Click "Manage BitLocker" next to D:
4. Enable automatic unlocking.

If you want to disallow other users, just use standard Windows filesystem permissions:

1. Right-click the drive in Computer
2. *Properties*
3. *Security*

Answer (score 1):

you can make some batch file and add it to startup...

something like:

- unlock partition with bitlocker
- kill explorer
- start explorer
- or logoff

btw. not shure if kill/start explorer would save all!

and for bitlocker cmd's [look here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894351%28WS.10%29.aspx)

probably something like that!

Answer (score 1):

This question should be on serverfault.com or superuser. Anyway, maybe http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424323%28WS.10%29.aspx will help.